# Execute a shell script after clicking on a action button in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I want to execute a shell script after clicking the action button in the shiny.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

 fluidPage(
    actionButton("buttonId", "run script")
  )
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$buttonId, {
      message("running script.R")
      system("/bin/bash /apps/shiny/mot/sh_saa.sh")
    })
  }
```

If I run `R` in the shell and then

```
system("/bin/bash /apps/shiny/mot/sh_saa.sh")
```

it works! However, it does not work when I click on the button. Any idea?
All three files, `server`, `ui` and  `sh_saa.sh` are in `mot`.

**Edit 1:**

I looked in the log files. One can see there the following error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)
```

the shell script is:

```
ssh -tt user@mashine<< EOF
cd /home/Deployment/test/
./stopSaa.sh
EOF
```

Comment: What does this message say? `message(file.exists('/bin/bash /apps/shiny/mot/sh_saa.sh'))`

Comment: Another question : are you running the code on a shiny-server? Shiny server runs with user `shiny` which might not have the privileges to execute the script.

Comment: yes I run the code on shiny server on a cetos 7. However -rwxr-xr-x  shiny   84 Aug  3 21:35 sh_saa.sh